# "mvn -version" not returning the version

Tags: linux, maven, ubuntu

I am trying to install maven on Ubuntu using the following steps :

1. user$ wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
2. user$ tar -zxvf apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
3. user$ export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH

on doing
user$ echo $PATH

cli returns : 
/usr/local/apachemaven3.3.9/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

but on executing

user$ mvn -version

cli returns :
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:

- maven
- maven2

Try: sudo apt-get install

Is any step missing here ?

JAVA_HOME is already set :

user$ echo $JAVA_HOME

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: replace `export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH` by `export PATH=USER/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH` where user is directory where you extracted archive

Comment: Why are you installing manually? You have a package manager for this which can do this much better and will avoid conflicts and keep it up to date.

Answer (score 0):

In your path, you have `/usr/local/apachemaven3.3.9/bin` instead of `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin`.

Also I recommand you use an environment variable like `MAVEN_HOME` to save the location of Maven directory : `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9`.

Then you can set your `PATH` to `${MAVEN_HOME}/bin:${PATH}`.

That way you won't have to change your `PATH` if you have to change your Maven directory or version for example. You only have to change your `MAVEN_HOME`.

Comment: Don't use MAVEN_HOME, M2_HOME etc. anymore. The only need to have it in the PATH that's it. Except of course of JAVA_HOME...

Answer (score 0):

You should set your environment variables in:

1. /etc/environment
2. /etc/profile

You can do it using the vi editor, and you'll need to it as super user. Like this:

sudo vi /etc/environment

Afterwards, restart your system or logout and log back in.